# My code is running before I press the button, can anybody tell me why?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I am making a javascript text-based game for my personal website, and I can not seem to figure out why  **my code is running before the button is pressed.** When I reload the page, the code runs without having to be executed by the button click. Can anybody tell me why? I am using vanilla javascript. Here is the code.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", everything(), false)

function everything() {
  var startButton = document.getElementById('Enter');
  /*The code below is the code I need to run when I press the Click to start button*/
  startButton.onclick = console.log("You started the game.")

}
```

```html
<h4 id="gameText">Click the button below to play.</h4> <br>

<button id="Enter" width=100px>Click to start</button> <br>

<button id="but1"> /\ </button> <br>

<button id="but2"> | </button> <br>

<button id="but3"> |</button> <br>
```

Comment: That part of the code is to ensure none of the bugs are due to JS running before the HTML loads.

Comment: Also duplicate of [“OnClick” events created through JavaScript are triggering immediately, not when the object is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24573046/4642212). The second argument of `addEventListener` and the value of `onclick` are supposed to be _functions_, not `undefined`. `everything() === undefined` and `console.log("You started the game.") === undefined`. You’re not binding event listeners.

Comment: user4642212 I am sorry, I did not mean to copy off of them. I could not find the answer when I looked it up, even on stackoverflow. I guess I am bad at looking things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is faulty.

```
startButton.onclick = console.log("You started the game.")
```

What you want to do here is register a callback but you are actually calling the function.

The minimal change you want is:

```
startButton.onclick = function(){ console.log("You started the game."); };
```

That way you make `onclick` to be a function that runs when you click the button instead of the result of `console.log`.

Comment: thank you for taking time out of your day to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("click", everything, false) // <= add click event 

function everything() {
  var startButton = document.getElementById('Enter');
  /*The code below is the code I need to run when I press the Click to start button*/
  startButton.onclick = console.log("You started the game.")

}
```

Comment: That code at the top is to make sure that the program doesn't run until the window loads. I don't want it to replace the use of my button